# Get checkbox value in django

Tags: python, django, input, submit

I have passed a python list (list_exp) in my html template and now i would like to get the result of my multiple checkbox in view.py with a dictionary.
{list_exp[0] : True/False, list_exp[1] : True/False.....}

```
<form action="" method="post">
{% for name in list_exp%}
<input type="checkbox" name="{{name}}"><label> Experiment : {{name}}</label>
<br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: During or after form validation?

Comment: Normally after you submit the form your backend would look for the requests args in this case whatever is in {{name}}, However I often use a jquery post to prevent defualts from happening.  Which then means I can do things like this on the template.
var value = $('#checkbox').is(':checked');
$.post(/endpoint, {"{{name}}": value}, function(data){});

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, if you give every input checkbox the same name, you can refer to the them as a list in your views.py.

So in the template:

```
{% for name in list_exp %}
   <input type="checkbox" name="list_exp"><label> Experiment : {{name}}</label>
   <br>
{% endfor %}
```

And then in the views.py:

```
request.POST.getlist('list_exp')
```

will return a list as expected